# How to get the 'value' of a html element in python-selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

In a html page I have the following snippet:

```
<div class="jupyter-widgets widget-hbox widget-text">
    <div class="widget-label" style="display: block;">Walltime:</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
</div>
```

in which the `input` element renders, like expected, as an *input* field. However, this input field has some value in it.

Using the inspector of the browser it is possible to select that element and use the following expression in the console to get that value:

$0.value

However, how to do this in python-selenium?

When I have the `input` element in a variable named 'input' I have tried the following:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value;", element)
```

which does not return the value in that input box, but `None` instead. How to do it correctly to retrieve the value from that 'input' box?

Comment: have you tried `element.text`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `get_attribute` you can get any attribute of an element! in your case:

```
element.get_attribute("value")
```

As @Guy commented *text is not part of the html* so don't use:

```
element.text
```

Comment: `element.text` won't work, the text is not part of the html.

Comment: @Guy I was just asking you why not to use `text` :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the value

```
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].value;', element)
```

You can also use `get_attribute()`

```
element.get_attribute('value')
```